# array_key_exists returns false although it shouldn't

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating an football script to get the correct name of a team. Here is my function wrapped in a class.

```
static function getMatchesName($league, $team){
    $eredivisie = array('PEC Zwolle' => 'PEC Zwolle',
                        'PSV Eindhoven' => 'PSV',
                        'SC Heerenveen' => 'SC Heerenveen',
                        'Ajax' => 'Ajax',
                        'AZ Alkmaar' => 'AZ',
                        'FC Twente' => 'FC Twente',
                        'Vitesse' => 'Vitesse',
                        'Cambuur' => 'Cambuur Leeuwarden',
                        'FC Groningen' => 'FC Groningen',
                        'Go Ahead Eagles' => 'Go Ahead Eagles',
                        'FC Utrecht' => 'FC Utrecht',
                        'Feyenoord' => 'Feyenoord',
                        'Heracles' => 'Heracles Almelo',
                        'Roda JC Kerkrade' => 'Roda JC',
                        'NAC Breda' => 'NAC Breda',
                        'RKC Waalwijk' => 'RKC Waalwijk',
                        'ADO Den Haag' => 'ADO Den Haag',
                        'NEC Nijmegen' => 'NEC');

    $leagues = array(57 => $eredivisie);

    if (!array_key_exists($league, $leagues)) return '1'; // return $team;

    var_dump(isset($leagues[$league][$team]));
    if (!array_key_exists($team, $leagues[$league])) return '2'; // return $team;
    else return $leagues[$league][$team];
}
```

I am calling this method from another script. If the league or team does not exist, the initial team name $team should be returned. It returns 1 or 2 at the moment for debugging purposes.

Now here's the thing: the `var_dump()` returns false in all cases. `is_string($team)` is true so `$team` is a string. When I run the function without variables like this `echo ClassName::getMatchesName(57, 'Heracles');` it returns 'Heracles Almelo' like it should.

PHP Version: 5.3.10

Any idea how I could possibly fix this?

**Solved:** Turned out I had to do a `trim()` on the `$team` variable in the other script.

Comment: I got the var_dump output `bool(true)`. What php version are you using? Do you enable the warning message? Because FYI, this code raise warning `array_key_exists($leagues[$league][$team])`: `PHP Warning:  array_key_exists() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given`

Comment: @ihsan Parameter thing was a stupid copy/paste mistake by me. PHP version added to the post.

Comment: What are the variables you are passing in?

Comment: 57 and 'Heracles'. As said, just running it works fine but when I run it from the other script is returns false. Even though `is_string` returns true on the 'team' variable.

Comment: here's php-fiddle http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/t98-zvx it totally works as expected. Where's the problem?

Comment: Make sure that the variables you use are containing the necessary value before passing to the static function, because just as @u_mulder said, the code works fine.

Comment: Okay, I'm glad this code isn't the problem but as I said in my opening post, I already knew that it worked the way @u_mulder showed in the phpfiddle. Although I'm 100% sure I'm passing the correct parameters I will investigate some more.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the help all of you!